# Parsing Soap response in php with key and value pair

Tags: php, parsing, curl, soap, xml-parsing

I am getting the following soap reponse.

```
    <soapenv>
    <soapenv:Body><res:ResultMsg >
    <Result>
        <ResultType>0</ResultType>
        <ResultCode>0</ResultCode>
        <ResultDesc>Processing</ResultDesc>
        <OriginatorID>2545imt56764</OriginatorID>
    <ResultParameters>
        <ResultParameter>
        <Key>firstname</Key>
        <Value>john</Value>
        </ResultParameter>
    <ResultParameter>
        <Key>lastname</Key>
        <Value>doe</Value>
    </ResultParameter>
    <ResultParameter>
        <Key>Country</Key>
        <Value>xxxx</Value>
    </ResultParameter>
    </ResultParameters>
    </Result>
   </res:ResultMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to retrieve the first name and last name from the code. The following is the code that am using.

```
  $doc->loadXML($rawXML);
    $ResultCode = $doc->getElementsByTagName('ResultCode')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $ResultDesc = $doc->getElementsByTagName('ResultDesc')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $OriginatorID = $doc->getElementsByTagName('OriginatorID')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $name = $doc->getElementsByTagName('value')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo $ResultCode"," ;
    echo $ResultDesc"," ;
    echo $OriginatorID",";
    echo $name",";
```

How can I be able to retrieve the last name and country values